# How to correct zero cell counts for odds ratio calculations when variable has >2 categories

Tags: r, glm

I am using R to calculate odds ratios for several univariate models with a binomial outcome.

The problem is, for some of my variables, I am getting the following error `glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred`. I have found that these variables commonly have at least 1 zero count cell.

It seems that the Haldane correction (0.5 is added to all cells of the contingency table) is commonly used when there is a zero count cell for a 2x2 contingency table. However, some of my variables have more than 2 levels.

Can I apply the Haldane correction for my variables with >2 categorical levels?
Or, is there an alternate recommendation to fix this problem?

Comment: This is more of a stats question than a programming question, so I have voted to migrate it to CrossValidated, our sister Stack Exchange site dedicated to statistics questions. You are more likely to get a good answer over there.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks for the recommendation, I will bring this over to Cross Validated.